# Receive data at node.js server from Ajax call in Object format

Tags: ajax, json, node.js

I am using Ajax call to post data from client side to node server and trying to receive data at server end, manipulate it(do some db query) and then return the response.

***client side code :***

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8888/ajaxRequest", 
    dataType: "json",
    data:  {name: "Manish", address: {city: "BBSR", country: "IN"}}
}).done(function ( data ) {
    console.log("ajax callback response:" + data);
});
```

***server side :***

```
var port = 8888;
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', request);
server.listen(port);

function request(request, response) {
    var store = '';
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/json"});
    request.on('data', function(data) {
        store += data;
    });
    request.on('end', function() {
        console.log(store);
        response.end(store);
    });
}
```

Problem : when I am consoling "store" variable in request end function I am getting something like this:

```
name=Manish&address%5Bcity%5D=BBSR&address%5Bcountry%5D=IN
```

I just want the same data at the server side what I sent in the Ajax 'data' parameter. I also tried, queryString.parse, JSON.parse() but no help. I just want my output as :

```
{name: "Manish", address: {city: "BBSR", country: "IN"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell jQuery that this is an JSON request:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8888/ajaxRequest", 
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    data:  JSON.stringify({name: "Manish", address: {city: "BBSR", country: "IN"}})
}).done(function ( data ) {
    console.log("ajax callback response:" + data);
});
```

This way, your request body will reach the server with the stringified JSON, so you'll be able to do the following:

```
request.on('end', function() {
    store = JSON.parse(store);
    console.log(store); // ta-daaa, Object!
    response.end(store);
});
```

Comment: just gave it a try, not working, still getting the url same string int he request.on('end', function).... (name=Manish&address%5Bcity%5D=BBSR&address%5Bcountry%5D=IN])

Comment: see updated answer, just added `JSON.stringify()` around `data`. This haves to work, it's how backbone does...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
...
response.end(JSON.stringify(store));
```

Comment: nothing happens, just returns the same string ("name=Manish&address%5Bcity%5D=BBSR&address%5Bcountry%5D=IN") with quotes around it.

Anyways I do not need the resulting object at client side, I just want to manipulate the string at server side.